# Lex/Yacc for Boolean Calculation

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I'm trying to write a program for calculating a NAND boolean expression using Lex/Yacc.

For example, if input is "true nand (false nand true)," my program should print "false"

This is what I have so far,, but I am really stuck

What am I missing or doing wrong?

## boolean.l

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}


%%
"true"|"false" {return BOOL;}
"nand"         {return NAND;}
[()]           {return yytext[0];}

%%
```

## boolean.y

```
%token BOOL NAND
%left NAND

%%
boolexp: boolexp NAND boolterm    {$$ = !($1 && $3);}
        | boolterm    {$$=$1;}
;

boolterm: '(' boolexp ')'
        | BOOL  {$$ = (strcmp($1, "true")) ? 1 : 0;} 
;

%%
#include <lex.yy.c>

int main(void) {
        yyparse();
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` returns 0 iff the values being compared are equal.  Your ternary statement is backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have a lot easier time if you made `TRUE` and `FALSE` two separate tokens.

```
%token TRUE FALSE NAND
%left NAND

%%
boolexp: boolexp NAND boolterm    {$$ = !($1 && $3);}
        | boolterm    {$$=$1;}
;

boolterm: '(' boolexp ')' {$$ = $2;}
        | bool  {$$ = $1;}
;

bool: TRUE {$$ = 1;}
    | FALSE ($$ = 0;}
;
```